# UpdatePanel after form submitted

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I am trying to have a `"Thank you for your message"` message show after you submit a form. It works, but the page refreshes, so I'm trying to use the UpdatePanel instead of just a Panel. The actual form is still in a Panel. The `"thank you message"` is in an UpdatePanel.

**Here is my code:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="pnlThankYouMessage" Visible="false">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="thankYou" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**This is what I have on the Onclick method on the submit button:**

```
pnlFormFields.Visible = false;
pnlThankYouMessage.Visible = true;
thankYou.Text = "Thank You for your inquiry.";
```

Comment: Which button triggers the submit? Have that button as an `AsyncPostbackTrigger` of the _UpdatePanel_. Also add `UpdateMode="Conditional"` on the update panel.

Comment: Please avoid using visible false in UpdatePanel instead use visible=false in label and at the time of button click set visible=true of the label and also take your form and label inside same `UpdatePanel`

Comment: Try setting `UpdateMode="Always"` of update panel